# Can an F# function be considered tail recursive it uses the TailCall .net opcode

Tags: performance, f#, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

Since .net has the [TailCall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.tailcall.aspx) opcode, 
can this be used to deterime if an F# function is truly tail recursive?

If it is true, has anyone made a VS add-in that identifies tail and non-tail functions?

Comment: In some cases the F# compiler will convert some recursion cases to something which resembles `goto` without using a `.tail` instruction - detecting this could be difficult

Comment: @Brain: Are you asking if I want to know when a function is tail recursive? If so, that should help me write more efficient code. It would be like instant feedback if I made something that was optimized out as tail recursive, and then with one wrong change made it none tail recursive. Think of it this way. You have code in production that is tail recursive, you put in the little change and it is now not tail recursive. It goes into production and all of a sudden starts doing stack overflows. You never saw it coming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx) on the F# team blog for a summary of how F# compiles tail calls.

In short,

1. Direct recursive tail calls are typically converted into loops.
2. Mutual recursion and indirect non-recursive tail calls are typically turned into .NET tail calls.

but see the full post for all of the gory details.

Comment: Nice answer, read the post. At the end it says "I hope that this information has been helpful.  My next post will cover ways to work around some of the limitations covered in this post." any idea on where is the next post?

Comment: @GuyCoder - good question.  It got put on the back burner as we started doing more of the type provider work, but I'll try to finish it up.

Comment: Can you talk about this in your next post? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2007/09/24/adventures-in-f-corecursion.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the compiler emits the `tail` call instruction, that call will be tail recursive (as of CLR 4, but there are still some exceptions, where it won't be actually tail recursive). But that doesn't necessarily mean that the whole function is tail recursive. For example, I can imagine QuickSort function compiled so that the first recursive call is not tail recursive and the second one is.

Also, just because some function does not contain the `tail` instruction, it doesn't necessarily mean that it is not tail recursive. The JIT compiler can recognize a tail call even without the `tail` instruction and optimize it as such.

What's more, the F# compiler sometimes compiles recursive functions in a non-recursive way. This is somewhat different than normal tail call optimization and the `tail` instruction is not used, but the overall effect is similar.